# Can a twitter-application be blocked?

Tags: twitter, tweepy, django-socialauth, python-social-auth

For 4 weeks, everything has been working smoothly - then all of a sudden **none** of the users of my application has been able to follow people. I quickly created a new application and tried with a couple of the same users, and it worked. My question then becomes, can an application be rate limited? Every other function (favorite, unfollow, direct messaging) works like a charm. The error it returns for every user is

```
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{'message': "You are unable to follow more people at this time. Learn more <a href='http://support.twitter.com/articles/66885-i-can-t-follow-people-follow-limits'>here</a>.", 'code': 161}]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling in the application's context or the user's context? You need to do this in the user's context, which means your app needs to be able to call twitter on their behalf. That requires you to build a workflow whereby the user can give you consent so you can obtain an application specific user token.

Comment: Of course, that is done. I'm invoking the API based on their information.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, didn't notice that can't even call the API without the user token. Please check this: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/20408

Answer (score 0):

Because you've exceeded their follow limits? From their support page:

> If you're unable to follow more accounts, you've probably hit a follow
>   limit. Twitter has imposed reasonable limits to help prevent system
>   strain and to limit abuse.

Your application needs to stop abusing their limits. It doesn't look like support can help. Do read [this page](https://support.twitter.com/entries/68916#) and try to conform to the rules.

Comment: According to their API - the limits are set to each user, and not the application. Althought, testing with a new twitter user on the very same application yields the same results.

Comment: I guess they do impose limits on entire apps, then. I can't find anything in their documentation.